# grep -v excludes a file it should not exclude

Tags: bash, grep

It seemed to me that `grep -v` displays the files that don't contain the following string.

How comes the file named highscore.txt doesn't appear when using `grep -v ".c"` ?

```
$ ls -1
a.out
easy.txt
hard.txt
highscores.txt
main.c
main.txt
util.c
$ ls -1 | grep -v ".c"
a.out
easy.txt
hard.txt
medium.txt
```

Comment: `.` is "any character" in regular expressions.

Comment: oh ok thank's, maybe you could write it as an answer to the question so I can accept it

Comment: In addition to what @BenjaminW. said, your regex will exclude `*.cpp`, `*.cs` even if you fix the `.`. You need to anchor like `\.c$`.

Comment: If you enable extended globbging, you can use `ls -1 !(*.c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `".c"` in your grep command is a regular expression, and `.` means "any character".

To fix this, you can

- Escape the period:

  ```
  grep -v '\.c$'
  ```

  I've added the "end of string" anchor `$` to exclude false positives for files like `something.cpp`.
- Use the `-F` option for "fixed strings":

  ```
  grep -vF '.c'
  ```

  Notice that this would also exclude `something.cpp`, which probably isn't what you want.
- Use extended glob patterns to exclude anything ending in `.c`:

  ```
  shopt -s extglob
  ls -1 !(*.c)
  ```

  Here, `*.c` is not a regular expression, but a glob pattern, where `.` is a literal period and has no special meaning.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, we edited at the same time.